# Can I print via CUPS on ARM device without drivers by installing CUPS onto an x86 server with drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, printing, cups, raspbian

I just spent a few frustrating hours troubleshooting on a Raspberry Pi 2 only to find out that it is impossible to print to my Canon printer natively using CUPS. Thankfully, my printer supports Google Cloud Print and I could just use a nice tool called CUPS Cloud Print to redirect my printing jobs to Google Cloud Print services and then to my printer without the need for drivers, however it is not optimal because there is a large lack in features (such as no duplexing).

I have an old desktop computer laying around as a "free" NAS box running Ubuntu 14.04.01 and I was wondering if it would be possible to use *that* as my CUPS server with **amd64** drivers so I could use CUPS on my Raspberry Pi 2 to send jobs to my printer over the server. My current printer is a Canon MF8580Cdw and it supports Google Cloud Print, Airprint, and tons of other network printing solutions. Is there maybe an easier way that I've been missing?

Comment: You most certainly can, it's just a configuration file- and testing nightmare. The whole printer driver thing is a joke... technically it would be cheap and easy to build an addon for CUPS that looks like Ezeep, maybe an owncloud module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may configure the printer on the Pi as raw printer port, so the actual driver is installed and run on the client, not on the server on the Pi.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329186/creating-a-raw-printer-queue-in-cups-host-and-adding-them-through-cups-client